# PL/SQL Triggers to update selected rows in column in another table

Tags: plsql, triggers, sql-update, multiple-tables

I'm trying to create a trigger for my 'rentals' table that will change the value in a certain column ('rent_avail') from another table when an update occurs in the former table. The idea is simple: when a dvd is returned to the dvd store (i.e. date_return has a date value, the dvd has now become available again for renting. Thus, my 'rent_avail' column for the record (dvd) in question should reflect this by being set to 'Y' (the alternative is 'null' when the dvd is currently being rented out). My trigger is being created without errors, but after an insert on the date_return column, all values in my DVD table are being changed. I want to know how can I simply modify the column values in 'rent_avail' column in my dvd table for only the row being updated! This is probably very trivial, but I have researched it and can't seem to find a solution easily..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RENTAL_RETURNS
AFTER UPDATE OF DATE_RETURN ON RENTAL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :OLD.DATE.RETURN IS NULL AND :NEW.DATE_RETURN IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE DVD SET RENT_AVAIL = 'Y' WHERE DVD.DVD_ID = DVD_ID;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: what is the name of foreign_key column dvd_id in RENTAL table?

Comment: My foreign key is DVD_ID in RENTAL TABLE, and also in DVD table..

Comment: I thought so :). Check my answer

Comment: That help's alot, Sandeep. Thanks a million. :) One last question, the new code changes the value of the rent_avail in DVD table alright, but if I make insert a new record into DVD, or insert a new instance of rental, it reverts all values in rent_avail back to null, so that there will only be a 'Y' in the recently updated record...Does this require another trigger?

Comment: First of all, if you can try to remove Trigger and adjust your code, but if currently you are not in position to do that then trigger is fine, but keep it in your future to do list to remove trigger dependencies.

Comment: About your question, Inserting Record in DVD will not change anything into RENTAL table, you have trigger on RENTAL not DVD and 2nd your's is a UPDATE trigger, so inserts in RENTAL table will not execute this trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your update statement is not picking dvd_id from parent table rebtal, but evaluating like where dvd_id = dvd_id which will always be TRUE. Just ad :OLD qualifier and you should be good, considering this is same column name (dvd_id) in rental table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RENTAL_RETURNS
AFTER UPDATE OF DATE_RETURN ON RENTAL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :OLD.DATE.RETURN IS NULL AND :NEW.DATE_RETURN IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE DVD SET RENT_AVAIL = 'Y' WHERE DVD.DVD_ID = :OLD.DVD_ID;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there's a period where there should be an underscore in the IF statement - I think it should read

```
IF :OLD.DATE_RETURN IS NULL AND :NEW.DATE_RETURN IS NOT NULL THEN`
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: And note that @Sandeep's comment on the DVD_ID is yet another part of the puzzle. Share and enjoy.